# Only one checbox checked with possibility check checkbox by div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have several checkboxs on site. This checkboxs can be `check` by div too, but only one checkbox can be `check` at a time. That is the problem. When I want click on checbox by div - it works.

When I want only one checbox checked at a time - it works. But when I want both functions at once - it doesn't.

So here is code (for example):

```
<div class="sth">
 <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck"><label>blabla</label>
</div>
<div class="sth">
 <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck"><label>blabla</label>
</div>
<div class="sth">
 <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck"><label>blabla</label>
</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
$("div.sth").on("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:checkbox')) return;

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    if( !checkbox.prop("checked") ){
        checkbox.prop("checked",true);
    } else {
        checkbox.prop("checked",false);
    }
});

$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/63/)**.

You should add the following line :

```
$('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
```

In your `"div.sth"` click event to uncheck the other checkboxes first then select the one related with clicked div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was so simpe... I struggled with this almost 2 hours. This works great, thx :)
Taking the opportunity I have one question: i have code like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pamudtzk/
How can I take a price (9,15) from <span>, added to this some coins and past to the <span> a bigger price?

Comment: You could give the span an identifier `id` or `class`??

Comment: I prefer to avoid this situation, because this box may be more than one (eg. 10), each with a different price tag in the <span> and different coins to add. That's why I have a problem. So eg. I click on checbox in box 3, and in <head> of box 3 the price is change.

Comment: @Sokołow check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pamudtzk/2/, i'm not sure if every box will be inside `item`.

Comment: Every box will be inside item. I did it a different way, but Your idea with find('h2 span') was great. Once more - thank You very much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105615/discussion-between-sokolow-and-zakaria-acharki).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using radio buttons instead and just styling them with CSS to look however you want?

Otherwise use the other answer, mine second portion of this was me misunderstanding the goal.